# Json schema conditional minLength for csv validation

Tags: csv, jsonschema

I need to use a csvValidator, I have found one with npm, who allow to specify validation rules, using the json schema. It's the first time I use it, but I have succed each of my validation requierement except for one (two actually, but they're of the same kind).

I have a field who can be empty, only if another field have a specific value. I've tried this, but unsuccesfully :

```
"properties":{
    "myVariable": {
            "type": ["string", "number"],
            "maxLength": 11,
            "if": {
                "properties": {
                    "devise": { "const" :"XPF"}
                }
            },
            "then": {
                        "minLength" : 0
            }
         }
}
```

I had read about conditional subsequence, but until now, I haven't found something that works.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close. You just need to move the conditional up a level. A sub-schema can only reference things within it's schema. That means that inside of the `/properties/myVariable` schema, you can't reference the "devise" property.

```
"properties":{
  "devise": { "type": "string" },
  "myVariable": {
    "type": ["string", "number"],
    "maxLength": 11,
  }
}
"if": {
  "properties": {
    "devise": { "const" :"XPF"}
  }
},
"then": {
  "properties": {
    "myVariable": { "minLength" : 0 }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for you answer. I've allready try this, but it doesn't works. I try it again once, maybe I had missed something, the first time.

Does the order have any importance ? I had just try to put device ahead of myVariable, in the Json Schema doesn't work better.

I'am on it since several hours. And I actually thing to do the conditionnal validation part, with a bash script. The json schema can  help to validate the most part. But I'am still interested by a way of doing this with json schema.

Comment: The pattern is correct, but I just realized that the `minLength` constraint doesn't make sense. Asserting that a string has a minimum length of 0 is always going to be true. I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: As check what version of JSON Schema you are using. If it's less than Draft-07, you won't be able to use `if`/`then`. I'll have to show you a different way.

Comment: It's for an optionnal field so minLength to 0 authirize an empty field , only if another field have a specific value.

Comment: I'm not sure, for the JSON Schema used. I check in the dependancies of csval the package npm I use, but I'am not sur what I looking for. It use @Hapi/joi who apprently is related to json schema, but I can't find any mention on the draft used

The doc of csval only get a link to the JSON Schema Reference

Comment: There's nothing in `/properties/myVariable` that constrains it to not be empty in the first place. Then adding `"minLength": 0` doesn't do anything because it's not possible for a string to have a negative length. So, unless by empty you mean null or undefined rather than empty string, the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Joi is not JSON Schema. They do similar things, but they aren't related.

Comment: It's maybe due to csval, but if I let the field empty it throw an error: "empty field isn't allowed". If I had NULL type, it throw also an error, if I doesn't set the field explicitly to NULL. 

I also have to mention that the csv input doesn't have quotes.

Comment: It sounds like you're dealing with a non-standard JSON Schema implementation. You might have better luck bringing this up with the author of the library.